# Тело и труп - это синонимы?

Tags: синонимы

Во фразах типа "несли тело", "на носилках лежало тело" и подобных стоит рассматривать слово "тело" как синоним слова "труп" или же оно выражает неизвестность между живым человеком и мёртвым? Если оно является синонимом, то как правильно выразить неизвестность?

---

Контекст: человек видит в окно, что на носилках несут кого-то, но понятия не имеет, кого и живой он или нет. Обращаясь к сидящему в комнате он говорит: "несут ..." - что должно быть вместо многоточия? Если сказать "человека", то вроде как будет восприниматься как живого, если сказать "труп" - как мёртвого. Если "тело" тоже означает мёртвого, то что-то варианты закончились...

Comment: Несут кого-то, но понятия не имеет живой ли? Определить просто — по положению этого кого-то. Традиция.

Answer (score 3):

Тело может быть и спящим. Если говорят про тело, что оно без признаков жизни - значит бывает и с признаками жизни. Про труп такого не слышал.

> Спящее тело Аэлиты вздрогнуло, она вздохнула, пробуждаясь, и
> затрепетала. [А. Н. Толстой. Аэлита. (Закат Марса.) (1939)]

Answer (score 1):

> Тело и труп - это синонимы?

Не совсем. Но в данном значении - скорее всего, да.

> Во фразах типа "несли тело", "на носилках лежало тело" и подобных
>   стоит рассматривать слово "тело" как синоним "трупа" или же оно
>   выражает неизвестность между живым человеком и мёртвым?

Первое. Тело=труп. Если бы не ваш вопрос, я бы и не подумал о каких-то иных возможностях. Но у автора, возможно, свой взгляд на проблему. Так что надо смотреть контекст, причем не просто текстовый, а во всей ситуации. Кто это сказал, в какой среде, кому адресовано... 
Допускаю, что у медиков или там судмедэкспертов, тело и труп - не синонимы. Но утверждать это наверняка не берусь.

> Если оно является синонимом, то как правильно выразить неизвестность?

Вот слово "неизвестность" мне здесь как-то совсем непонятно. Говорящий не знает, кого несут? Ну тогда он и должен сказать "нечто, напоминающее мертвого". Ситуация несколько надуманная, признаться.

Видимо, речь идет о неопределенности, то есть когда говорящий не хочет или не имеет права употреблять слово "труп" или синоним. В специальных текстах это называется "без признаков жизни". Оно по замыслу как раз и означает неопределенность - факт смерти не установлен. К сожалению, в быту это выражение трактуют именно как установленный факт, а следовательно, и этот вариант не годится для широкого употребления. Боюсь, и тут синонима из одного слова не найти...

Comment: Контекст: человек видит в окно, что на носилках несут кого-то, но понятия не имеет, кого и живой он или нет. Обращаясь к сидящему в комнате он говорит: "несут ..." - что должно быть вместо многоточия? Если сказать "человека", то вроде как будет восприниматься как живого, если сказать "труп" - как мёртвого. Если "тело" тоже означает мёртвого, то что-то варианты закончились...

Answer (score 1):

Я вообще предпочел бы не употреблять какое-либо однозначное определение в этой ситуации. Можно просто сказать:

> Несут кого-то...

или более развернуто:

> Несут кого-то на носилках... Не могу понять, жив ли этот человек.